# How to gain adminstration rights in the administrator account?

Tags: login, administrator

I am trying to set up a Web server (apache2) in Windows 10, but when I put a index html into the htdocs folder, it said I don't have administration rights, but I am log in to my administration account! Anyone how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost certainly logged in with an account **capable** of being elevated to do 'admin-stuff'.  But not actually using this all the time.  This has been the default in windows since Vista.

This is why you sometimes get those UAC warnings when a program actually wants to use those admin rights.  (Assuming you did not disable UAC, which is not recommended. It is there for a good reason.)

This means that you want to start an explorer **as admin**. E.g.

- From the command prompt with 'runas'
- Or by going to the exexutable, **right** clicking and selecting the 'run as administrator' option.

Then use that explorer/program to copy files.

---

This was the quick way around it on a test host (test is assumed since you are using a PREVIEW of an OS). The proper solution is to create a security group, make the webroot owned by that group (and writable by people in that group) and to add your account to that group.